# Inserting compile date/time into the code in XC8

Tags: pic, microchip, xc8

I'm in the process of writing code for a real time clock, and I want to compile the code with constants for the date/time of compilation to burn onto the clock immediately upon programming.

I believe I have seen this done before, but my searches have proved fruitless. Is there some kind of compile time macro that would do this? Something like:

```
rtc.second = __COMPILE_SECOND;
rtc.minute = __COMPILE_MINUTE;
rtc.hour   = __COMPILE_HOUR;
rtc.date   = __COMPILE_DATE;
rtc.month  = __COMPILE_MONTH;
rtc.year   = __COMPILE_YEAR;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [XC8 C Compiler Users Guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002053E.pdf), page 229:-

5.14.3 Predefined Macros

```
__DATE__ to indicate the current date eg. May 21, 2004 
__TIME__ to indicate the current time eg. 08:06:31
```

You can parse these strings to get numbers compatible with your rtc, but what's the point of a real time clock that doesn't have the real time?

Anyway, look at this [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697820/how-to-use-date-and-time-predefined-macros-in-as-two-integers-then-stri) for a way to do it.

Comment: This will work. And this is just for setting the RTC on compile. After that, the RTC will maintain time. This is still in early development and I was annoyed with constantly having to update those constants before I compiled to put the correct time on.